# Coloring the dates in calendar using swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

i am trying to display a calendar where different days are colored differently (based on data extracted from a core data stack).

I could not find a calendar UI component in swift? (Why is that, btw?). Is there an easy way to integrate calendar in a view controller + access the cells of the calendar and change their background color, for example?

Thanks!,

Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are new to swift/ ios development?  The short answer is there is no built in UI component because Apple did not make one.

However, that being said, you have several options. Many people have attempted to roll their own and they have their code open sourced. Better yet, they have made the integration of their code to your code very easy.

Ever heard of Cocoapods? If not download, and it should help you. It is a dependency manager that let you add (and remove) 3rd party developer code to your project very easily. Once you have cocoapods installed, you can now add 3rd party code (typically called `pods`) to your code.

Since youre looking for a UI calendar components, you can find a list to choose from at this [link](https://cocoapods.org/?q=calenda). Just read the site to find out how to add pods to your project. Its very easy.

If for some reason you cant use cocoapods, then try cocoacontrols.com and look for a calendar there. Although the ones there are not as good as the first i suggested they are worth a look.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Yes, i am relatively new to swift. I did end up using cocoapods and installed CV Calendar. Worked out pretty well. had to thrash around a bit to get it to do what i wanted.

Comment: yea, thats the thing about CVCalendar. I had to trash around a bit too much on it. So i would up creating my own Cocoapod. Best of luck